# Hacer que sscanf se ejecute varias veces hasta terminar el string

Tags: array, c, string, archivo

Necesito saber como ejecutar varias veces la propuesta que tengo aqui para poder almacenar todos los datos para una posterior elaboracion, como no todas las lineas son iguales habia pensado en que hiciese una orden hasta que acabase de leer la linea del string(ya que todas tienen un formato igual seria facil). Adjunto un ejemplo (Lo que estoy intentando conseguir es recoger los marcajes):

```
JORNADA NOMBRE  APELLIDOS   MARCAJES
08:00   Julia   Gonzalez    8:45E 14:50S
06:00   Antonio Lopez Herrera   8:00E 14:45S 16:00E 17:00S
07:36   Maria   Perez Alonso    8:00E 14:45E 15:30E 17:00S
08:00   Andrés  Gomez   8:05E 14:45S 15:30E 17:00S
08:00   Sara    Martinez Conde  8:00E 14:45S 15:30E 16:45S 18:00E 20:00S
```

Aqui dejo el codigo que tengo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){
    char A[100],hora[100],nombre[100],apellidos[100],B[100],C[100];
    int h[100],m[100],h1[100],m1[100],i=0;

FILE *fichero;
fichero=fopen("Hola2.txt","r"); //Aqui abro el archivo de ejemplo y recojo la primera linea para mover el puntero//
fgets(A,100,fichero);

while(fscanf(fichero,"%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t",hora,nombre,apellidos)==3){ //hago un bucle para que recoja los datos//
                                                                            //aqui no hay problema porque todos son iguales//
fscanf(fichero,"%[^\n]",B);
        sscanf(B,"%i:%iE %i:%iS",&h[i],&m[i],&h1[i],&m1[i]);
            i=i+1; //Aqui es donde nose que hacer ya que cada linea va a ser distinta //
}



fclose(fichero);

}
```

Comment: y por qué no usas `getline` para obtener cada línea?

Comment: Que diferencia habria con lo que ya tengo? lo tengo montado de tal forma que me da la hora el nombre etc lo que me falta es saber como hacer continuar el sscanf para que labergue todas las posibles entradas y salidas

Comment: Lo difícil sería al procesar los apellidos, pues puede haber 1 o 2 apellidos, si no defines un delimitador de datos sería bastante difícil saber que dato corresponde al apellido (al menos que establezcas un formato estándar para el fichero)

Comment: pero eso no pasa lo mismo con los marcajes ? ya que puede haber 2 , 4 o incluso 6 , seria el mismo problema que tengo ahora mismo

Comment: al estar al último se puede idear una mejor solución, pero sí tienes razón, también pasaría lo mismo. Te recomendaría que uses un delimitador para los datos, con eso todo sería más fácil y podría darte una respuesta

Comment: los unicos delimitadores que hay son las tabulaciones entre los diferentes tipos de datos pero luego dentro del mismo tipo de datos solo hay espacios como separadores , y es que no se como hacer esto xd

Comment: dejame terminar el programa y te doy la respuesta :D

Comment: Jope pues muchas gracias jo c:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te decía en los comentarios, si no hay un delimitador el trabajo será más complejo, sin embargo me dijiste que el separador era una tabulación, con ello ya se puede empezar a hacer algo. Teniendo un delimitador o separador podemos particionar cada línea y obtener un array con cada elemento, esto lo podemos conseguir con la función `strtok`, además opté por usar la función `getline` para poder obtener cada linea del archivo.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    const char* filename = "input.txt";

    FILE* input_file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!input_file)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    char *contents = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    char* sep ="\t"; //definimos el tabulador como separador


    while (getline(&contents, &len, input_file) != -1){ //obtenemos cada linea
      char *line = strtok(contents, sep); //separaos la linea
      while(line!=NULL){ //iteramos para imprimir cada resultado
        printf("%s ", line); //imprimimos para ver el resultado
        line = strtok(NULL, sep);
      }
    }

    fclose(input_file);
    free(contents);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

La función `strtok` es un tokenizador y devuelve un puntero que apunta a una cadena que termina cero que indica el siguiente token. Ese token lo podemos almacenar en donde queramos y de la forma en que queramos, con lo que ya podríamos armar un array que contenga todos los elementos de cada fila, solo es cuestión de crear un array e ir colocando los datos por medio de un bucle `for`.